# How to save a json list into the database using a single button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

here's is the deal, I need to save a form into a table using json but there's a problem, every time I put a new row into the table the json simply ignores the new one and persist the first row again. Here are the codes I'm using:

This is a part of the function that throws a "virtual" tr into my view:

```
 var cnpjSoftwareHouse = $("#cnpjSoftwareHouse").val(),
    nomeRazao = $("#nomeRazao").val(),
    nomeContato = $("#nomeContato").val(),
    uf = $("#uf").val(),
    telefone = $("#telefone").val(),
    codMunicipio = $("#codMunicipio").val(),
    email = $("#emailSoftwareHouse").val();
    var tr =   
            '<tr id="tabelaV">'+
                '<td><label class="input"><input id="cnpjSoftwareHouseV" name="cnpjSoftwareHouse[]" value="'+cnpjSoftwareHouse+'" /></td></label>'+
                '<td><label class="input"><input id="nomeRazaoV" name="nomeRazao[]" value="'+nomeRazao+'" /></td></label>'+
                '<td><label class="input"><input id="nomeContatoV" name="nomeContato[]" value="'+nomeContato+'" /></td></label>'+ 
                '<td><label class="input"><input id="ufV" name="uf[]" class="none" value="'+uf+'" placeholder="" /></td></label>'+
                '<td><label class="input"><input id="telefoneV" name="telefone[]" value="'+telefone+'" /></td></label>'+
                '<td><label class="input"><input id="codMunicipioV" name="codMunicipio[]" value="'+codMunicipio+'" /></td></label>'+
                '<td><label class="input"><input id="emailSoftwareHouseV" name="emailSoftwareHouse[]" value="'+email+'" /></td></label>'+
                '<td><label class="input"><button type="button" id="ok" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addInfoCadastro()" >Confirmar</button></td></label>'+
                '<td><label class="input"><button type="button" id="remover" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="remover()" >Remover</button></td></label>'+
                '</tr>';
            $('#grid').find('tbody').append(tr);
```

And here is the part of the Json that receives the values of the inputs above:

```
    var objectListSoftwareHouse = [ {
    cnpjSoftwareHouse : $("#cnpjSoftwareHouseV").val(),
    nomeRazao : $("#nomeRazaoV").val(),
    nomeContato : $("#nomeContatoV").val(),
    uf : $("#ufV").val(),
    telefone : $("#telefoneV").val(),
    codMunicipio: $("#codMunicipioV").val(),
    email : $("#emailSoftwareHouseV").val(),
} ];
```

I thought I could use some kind of arrayList, but I have no Idea how to start it, to better understand, I want to save all the "virtual table rows" at once using the same button, I couldn't find a way to do it... The Json always saves the first and ignores the rest of the rows...

Comment: What is a JSON function?

Comment: Sorry bro I think I didn't express myself right... I'm a noob in development and sometimes I don't know how to explain it very well ... hahaha

Comment: There's nothing even resembling JSON here.

Comment: It sounds like you are inserting multiple rows containing elements that (illegally) share an ID and are then trying to read the values using the (not really) unique identifier and are surprised that the browser gives you the first match. If so, you really need to rethink how you are referencing your elements.

Comment: thanks Quentin I'll try to find a better way!